# Ender 3 nozzle temp turns off briefly at start of print

Tags: nozzle, temperature

When I need to print higher-temp filament at 225 °C the nozzle temp turns off for just a second but this is enough to send the temp down to about 200 °C before it recovers to print temp.  This jams up the nozzle and I get stringing as it tries to print the brim.  Sometimes this is no big deal, other times I have to start over.  I can't find any control in Cura for this; my initial print and final temps are all at 225 °C.  Seems like some auto-program for the initial homing in the firmware or something.

I'm using a BLTouch.

Comment: Looks like you should do [PID Autotune](https://teachingtechyt.github.io/calibration.html#pid) for higher temperature.